# Regex for checking the last character

Tags: ruby, regex

How can I check if the last character of a string is `' '` or `','`?

I know for checking last character of string we need use `$`, and I made this regex for checking that the last character is `','`:

```
/\,$/
```

But I also need to check whether it's a space or not.

It will be very helpful if you give suggestion for making a regex like this.

Comment: Careful. `$` is end of *line* in Ruby, not end of *string*. You want `\z` for end of string. Two comments on the answer mention this but it is such a common error with Ruby regexes that it needs to be mentioned more times.

Comment: i mean to say only space, not white space, updated OP

Comment: (1) The backslash in your regex, while doing no harm, is meaningless. (2) If you want to check for a space instead of a comma, why not simply writing a space instead of a comma? `/ \z/`

Comment: I believe you are looking for `str[/[, ]]\z/`, which will return a space, comma or `nil`. You could instead use the regex `/(?:,| )\z/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `[]` to provide a set of characters:

```
[,\s]\z
```

which means, that you want either `,` or space character at the end of the string

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i don't understand your point, can you explain me ?

Comment: @Vishal Igor fixed his answer, nothing to explain.

Comment: Use `[,\s]\z`. `$` means "end of line", not "end of string"

Comment: Igor, can you please update answer as per @Phlip's suggestion ?

Comment: This fails on a multiline string that has _no trailing space or comma_, e.g. on `"foo,\nbar"`. **Always** prefer `\A` and `\z` matchers over `^` and `$` unless you explicitly want to match the _end of line_, not the _end of string_. NB: OP wanted to match characters in the _end of the string_.

Answer (score 4):

Regexps don't come for free and are often [much slower](https://medium.com/@Bakku1505/ruby-start-with-end-with-vs-regular-expressions-59728be0859e) than using a simple method on String.

Therefore I would suggest to not use a regexp in thus case but  `String#end_with?` instead:

```
string.end_with?(' ', ',')
```

IMHO it is also easier to read and to understand too.

Comment: For `str = "It's a fine day "` and `n = 10_000_000` I compared `n.times { str.end_with?(' ', ',') }` with `n.times { str.match? /[ ,]/ }`. The former took 1.79 seconds, the latter, 1.58 seconds.

Comment: Sure, the pure string methods are usually faster than the regexp versions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dot `.` to match any character except a new line. When you use the `s` flag, the dot can also match a new line.

```
/.$/s
```